# String to sharedpreference android

Tags: android, string, sharedpreferences

I have an login screen for my app. (spinner, edittext, button) and i want to store the spinner selected item and the inputted text to sharedpreferences. to use everywhere in the app.

**code**

```
Button lgnbutton;
EditText lgnfield;
Spinner lgnspinner;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

lgnbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.loginbutton);
lgnfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.loginfield);
lgnspinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.loginspinner);





lgnbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String ID = lgnfield.getText().toString();
        String Type = lgnspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();


        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
}    
}
```

Also it would be nice to skip the loginactivity and proceed to the mainactivity.

Comment: [See this tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-shared-preferences.html)

Comment: Do you need to save it into sharedpreferences, or can you just pass it as an extra?

Comment: I need every time the app restarts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store login details and spinner selected item  as in SharedPreferences

```
lgnbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

         ID = lgnfield.getText().toString();
         Type = lgnspinner.getSelectedItem().toString();

        SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = loginpreferences.edit();
        prefsEditor.putString("ID", ID);
        prefsEditor.putString("Type", Type);
        prefsEditor.commit();

        Intent myIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        LoginActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }
});
```

and in `onCreate` of `LoginActivity` check if login details exist in `SharedPreferences` if yes then move to `MainActivity` as :

```
SharedPreferences loginpreferences;
String ID="",Type="";
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    loginpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", 
                                            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);

    ID = loginpreferences.getString("ID", "");
    Type = loginpreferences.getString("Type", "");

     if(!ID.equalsIgnoreCase("") && !Type.equalsIgnoreCase(""))
      {
        //move to MainActivity
      }else
     {
       //stay in LoginActivity
     }
```

Comment: @Georggroenendaal : what error you are getting make sure you have added `SharedPreferences loginpreferences;` before onCreate and `loginpreferences = this.getSharedPreferences("loginPrefs", 
                                            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);`
 inside onCreate of Activity

Comment: @Georggroenendaal : if you are facing any issue in adding current code then just use this login class http://pastebin.com/9nhFEB3X

Answer (score 2):

Call this on spinner click

```
   SavePreferences("spinner_item",  mySpinner.getSelectedItem().toString());
```

Body of SavePreferences method.

```
     private void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString(key, value);
        editor.commit();
       }
```

call this method to load spinner item.

```
private void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String strSavedMem = sharedPreferences.getString("spinner_item", "");
     }
```